# Is it possible to use the 'using' statement in my aspx views? (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This likely applies to non MVC too.  But, Is it possible to use the 'using' statement in my aspx views?

Reason is that I have the pages reference resource files for localised strings.  And some of these resource references are quite long - it's really cluttering my code.

Since most of the time these resources are in a namespace specifially for the view, I'd just like to put a 'using Resources.This.that' at the top of the page.  I don't seem to be able to though - is there a way?

Thanks

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Do you mean like

```asp
<%@ Import namespace="MyProgram.MyNamespace" %>
```

Also, inside the root `<configuration>` tag of web.config, you can add:

```asp
<system.web>    
    <pages>
       <namespaces>
          <add namespace="System" />
          <add namespace="System.Collections" />
          <add namespace="System.Collections.Specialized" />
          <add namespace="System.Configuration" />
          <add namespace="System.Text" />
          <!-- etc -->
       </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

Comment: You mean under the `system.web` tag not in the root of the *web.config*?