# Add a reference to ASP.NET MVC ASPX page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, reference, html-helper

I have some HTML Helpers that I imported from an external project.  How do I reference them within the ASPX file?

Currently I get an error similar to the following:

```
Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<LC.TLAdminMVC.DAL.BusinessObjects.CompanySingleViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'Configurator' and no extension method 'Configurator' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<LC.TLAdminMVC.DAL.BusinessObjects.CompanySingleViewModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use the 'using' statement in my aspx views? (ASP.NET MVC)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697169/is-it-possible-to-use-the-using-statement-in-my-aspx-views-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

To better understand your situation can you answer one question.

Have you placed the helper methods inside the aspx files or are they external?

If they are external:

1. Make a directory in your solution named: app_code
2. Create a new file, whatever name (we'll call it 'Content')
3. When you want to use the helper method just call Content.methodName(params)

If they are internal:

Try checking if they are not nested inside a block.

Hope this helps,