# Shortened namespace alias in aspx

Tags: asp.net

I have a using statement defined like this in codebehind:

```
using Name = Extremely.Long.And.Unwieldy.Namespace
```

I want to be able to do this in  my aspx page:

```
<%=Name.Type %>
```

So far the best I have come up with is this:

```
<%=Namespace.Type %>
```

using the technique shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697169/is-it-possible-to-use-the-using-statement-in-my-aspx-views-asp-net-mvc).

Can I do any better?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Name=Extremely.Long.And.Unwieldy.Namespace" %>
```

Answer (score 4):

I found a reference to being able to use the import tag for namespace aliasing.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="myAlias=System.MyNamespace" %>
```

[source](http://ctrlf5.net/?p=187)

Comment: That link is broken.