# asp.net directive that does the same thing as VB.Net "Imports ="

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

The VB.Net `Imports` statement allows you to create aliases, like this:

```
Imports Utils = MyCompany.Utils
```

That lets you use `Utils` in your code to represent `MyCompany.Utils`, which would be useful if you are importing other namespaces that also define a class called `Utils`.

I have an .aspx page in VB, and I would like to do this, but there doesn't seem to be a directive I can use.  `<%@ Import ... %>` doesn't seem to support aliasing.  I can't use `Imports` in a `<script runat="server">` tag either... it gives me an error message.

How can I get this aliasing?

Comment: Is doing it in the code behind an option?

Comment: There is no code-behind for this page

Comment: Never mind... I found it in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001594/shortened-namespace-alias-in-aspx... It's <%@ Import Namespace="Name=Extremely.Long.And.Unwieldy.Namespace" %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a directive for it:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Utils = MyCompany.Utils" %>
```