# Alias Generic Type With ASP.Net Import Directive in VB.Net Page

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I can't seem to import a generic type on an ASP.Net page set to a language of "vb":

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" %>
<%-- This works fine. --%>
<%@ Import Namespace="MyString=System.String" %>
<%-- This gives an error. --%>
<%@ Import Namespace="MyList=System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.String)" %>
<%-- Error: "The 'namespace' attribute cannot contain spaces." --%>
```

Note that I'm NOT interested in these alternatives (for boring reasons you don't care about):

- Alter the web.config.
- Alter the code-behind.
- Use the code-behind instead of the page.
- Using C# instead of VB.Net.
- Googling (the MSDN page makes no mention of generic types).
- Modifying the app.config.
- Adding the namespace to the "imported namespaces" via the
  "References" tab in the project settings.
- Workarounds (I already have workarounds, but I want to see if this
  can be done properly)

Is it possible to alias a generic type on a VB.Net ASP.Net page, or is this an oversight by Microsoft?

Comment: Same as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001594/shortened-namespace-alias-in-aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, bad news:

1. You can't *alias* a generic type anywhere in .NET (may have changed recently, don't think so).
2. You can't import a namespace with a space in it, in ASP.NET.  It's the parser for the ASPX that's the issue.  Yep, Microsoft oversight.  Since C# would be `List<System.String>`, it would not throw the error.  They left out VB again.