# How to add alias to import namespace in global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

This is how you import in global.asax

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Some.Namespace" %>
```

I want to create alias for that namespace. Something like

```
using alias = Some.Namespace;
```

in c# class.

How to do it? Thanks

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? c# not using `Import` instead of use `using`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this:

Where Name is the alias name.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Name=Some.Namespace" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001594/shortened-namespace-alias-in-aspx)
Try this

```
<%@ Import Namespace="myAlias=System.MyNamespace" %>
```