# Bind Telerik Grid

Tags: telerik

I am binding Gird like below with the Model named "Employee"

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Grid<Employee>() 
             .Name( "EmployeeGrid" ) 
    .Columns(colums => colums.Bound(E => E.EmployeeID)) %>   


But I am getting the below error in this line Grid<Employee>()
```

The type or namespace name 'Employee' could not be found

I have three grids in one view so I cannot refer any particular model name using @model in first line of view.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that the View does not know the Type 'Employee' . 
You have to write in the first line:

```
<%@ Import namespace="MyProgram.FolderOfEmployeeClass" %>
```

info of the using statement in aspx files:

[Is it possible to use the 'using' statement in my aspx views? (ASP.NET MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697169/is-it-possible-to-use-the-using-statement-in-my-aspx-views-asp-net-mvc)

**piece of advice:** user the Razor engine instead of aspx. This is much more easier to use!